# What's the structure of "inorganic benzene"?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds, lewis-structure

Can anyone give me a possible structure for a compound called "inorganic benzene"?

Comment: @Agriculturist How is that a dupe?

Comment: @bon I see your point - missed the difference between benzene and inorganic benzene.

Answer (score 7):

"Inorganic benzene" also known as **borazine** has a molecular formula of $\ce{B3N3H6}$.

[image]

[image]

It is a planar structure. Both B and N are sp2 hybridised. It is called "inorganic benzene" as it is isoelectronic with benzene.

[image]

Comment: What are the sources of pics?